# Split string either side of space, save as independent variables

Tags: r, split

Consider:

```
string <- "PBF.csv AAV.csv"
split <- strsplit(string, " ")
> split
[[1]]
[1] "PBF.csv" "AAV.csv"
```

Both strings are split into the same variable. 
Is there a way to split into separate variables? 
Where I can access individually via:

```
split[1]
split[2]
```

?

Comment: nm looks this this worked: split[[1]][2]

Comment: `strsplit` returns a list with an element for each input string. While that can be helpful, if you know you're passing in a single string, it's not uncommon to see `split_vector <- strsplit(some_string)[[1]]`. Like any hardcoding of indices, it's not usually a good choice for programmatic usage, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unlist()` comes to the rescue:

```
> split <- unlist( split )
> split[ 1 ]
[1] "PBF.csv"
> split[ 2 ]
[1] "AAV.csv"
```

Comment: cool decided to go for: split <- unlist(strsplit(split, " "))

Comment: I guess you mean `split <- unlist(strsplit(string, " "))`  ;-)